# Finding nearest neighbors for each target location

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have a three dimensional data. The first two columns are X and Y which are the X,Y coordinates in 2D cartesian coordinate system. Third column Z is the height value at each X,Y location. I am trying to use SciKit Learn's KNeighborsRegressor function to find regression value at each X,Y location based on average of 50 nearest neighbors around it. I need to output which 50 X,Y locations are being averaged. In the image below green is the target location and red indicates the nearest neighbors. I need X,Y coordinates of the neighbors at each location.

[image: k nearest neighbors]

Here is the code I have to give me predicted value but as stated above I need to know for each predicted value which 50 X,Y locations were used.

```
knn_z = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=50)
x_columns = ['X','Y']
y_column = ['Z']
knn_z.fit(df[x_columns],df[y_column])
df['NN_Z'] = knn_z.predict(df[x_columns])
```

I will greatly appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the function kneighbors in the KNeighborsRegressor class for example:

```
knn_z.kneighbors(df[x_columns]),50,True)
```

you can read more about the function [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.kneighbors)